# Mirror X Axis Tool Not Working on Specific Vertex, but works on others?

Tags: modeling, rigging, edit-mode, mirror, shape-keys

Is there a way to reset my mesh or fix my vertex that won't mirror along the X axis?

In the image below you can see it works on multiple points

[image]

But for this one vertex, the mirror isn't working and I don't know how to solve that issue

[image]

How are the surrounding vertexes mirroring properly, yet this one vertex isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring back symmetry to your object, select all and go into *Mesh > Symmetrize*:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! I knew there was a simple way to do it

Comment: so when I did it in edit mode it worked, but when I switched back to object mode, half my character is missing now...??

Comment: that's weird, could you please share this part of your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: ah I had to delete my previous shape keys first, then redo it and now it works.